# What is dbus-daemon used for by nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, process, dbus

I created a nodejs server app that is using a few modules like ssh2, child_process, puppeteer, ws, sqlite, and when this app runs I see a "dbus-daemon" process with message+ as user that makes CPU usage rise logarithmically in a period of a few days to 100% making the entire server unresponsive.

Does anyone know why would nodejs use this process for?
In the app I am spawning a few child processes that communicate with each other via `message` events. Could that be the reason? Because dbus is apparently a messaging system

My app itself does not hog CPU because I am monitoring it with PM2 and it's always under 5%. But for some reason it makes this dbus thing consume cpu

Comment: hi i'm not good in this kind of things but i found this out of curiosity : https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html

Comment: dbus is for inter-process communication. As far as I can tell, the usual issue that causes this is run-away process creation: Something is constantly creating new processes that want to use dbus. As the number of dbus requests over time increase, dbus requires more and more CPU to handle them. I wonder if something in your node app is creating processes in an uncontrolled way.

Comment: I am running `fs.open('/proc/' + pid + '/stat')` every few seconds to get some real time statistics. Could that be the issue?

Comment: do you close the file after?

Comment: no lol. but shouldn't node.js auto-close it?

Comment: @Alex Can you please mimic running the application without the child process? And please take a look at this, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/438023

Comment: When you are already aware which process is eating up the space, diagnosing on it directly might be useful. You can isolate if the issues is with your project or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ouroborus stated in the question comments, dbus is used for inter-process communication.Your initial idea that something in your app is firing these up is highly probable. Running within a clean linux environment such as a lightweight dedicated container will exclude the origin to be from system; namely the system-wide dbus daemon instance. Leaving **your app and its dependencies** to investigate.

Depending on what linux environment you are using, you can monitor dbus processes - but from your question I understand you have already checked. If that only points to your app, then I'm quite certain that **one of your dependencies/packages is causing the issue**. I've had a similar issue with a system daemon being autolaunched again and again due to an older package I was using (that had no check for existing instances).

**Try updating all your packages/dependencies or else removing them temporarily in batches to find the trouble maker.**

There is a small change that you can also resolve the issue by specifying the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variabele (a quick search on howto for your enviro). If this variable is unset, it is possible that a process will attempt to invoke `dbus-launch` with the `--autolaunch` option to start up a new session bus. And if it keep losing track of it's open session busses, it will keep launching new ones.